# how @Autowired annotation worked without registering AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

Tags: spring

I just need to know how @Autowired annotation worked here without configuring AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor instance

```
package com.mmeqbel.springcontainer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class SpringContainerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var app = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        var car = app.getBean(Car.class);
        System.out.println(car);
    }
}

@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public Car car() {
        var car = new Car();
        car.setBrand(env.getProperty("car.brand"));
        return car;
    }
}

class Car {
    private String brand;

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "brand='" + brand + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I checked the docs for AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, and i couldn't find how this post-processor get implicitly registered in my example

Comment: It is part of the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 1):

The `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` creates an [`AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java). Which in turn will call [`AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java) [which will register](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigUtils.java#L148) multiple `Bean[Factory]PostProcessor` s in the `ApplicationContext.

It will always register (if not explicitly avaialable) the following

- `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor`
- `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`
- `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`
- `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` (if available)
- `EventListenerMethodProcessor`
- `DefaultEventListenerFactory`

Next to that it will also set some additional configuration on the `BeanFactory`/`ApplicationContext` which make sense for Java based configuration:

- `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator` is set to determine which dependency to inject based on the `order` and `@Order`.
- `ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver` is set to resolve dependencies using the current context and honouring `@Lazy`/`@Qualifier`.

This is all done as it simply makes sense to have all of these in a Java based configuration setting. The same would be set if you use XML and use one of:

- `<context:annotation-config />`
- `<context:component-scan ... />`

Each situation will call the `AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors` method to setup the proper parsing and annotation handling.